# Detecting multiple objects at a time with VNCoreMLRequest?

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I've got a VNCoreMLRequest set up that is working fine

```
extension CameraVC : AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
          print("Camera was able to capture a frame: ", Date())

        guard let pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
        guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Resnet50().model) else { return }

        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (finishedReq, err) in
            if err != nil { print(err?.localizedDescription) ; return }

            guard let results = finishedReq.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else { return }
            guard let firstObservation = results.first else { return }
            print(firstObservation.identifier, firstObservation.confidence)

        }
       try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])
    }
}
```

This request returns an array of what the request believes it is looking at, the first item in the list being the best guess.

I'm wondering if there's a way to detect multiple unique objects at the same time using this technology? If I were to have an apple and a banana in frame at the same time, is there a way to detect both objects instead of the camera trying to figure out what one prominent object can be found in the frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this but not using ResNet50.

ResNet50 is a classification model, which can only tell you about the "main topic" of the image. If there are an apple and a banana in the image, it may have high scores for apple and for banana in its top-5 predictions (like 40% apple and 35% banana and 25% other things) but that's not really what you're looking for.

The better solution is to use an object detection model, which not only tells you what the individual objects are in your image but also where they are located.